# Not able to install mysql on Ubuntu 14.2

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am trying

```
# sudo apt get install mysql-server-5.6
```

Executing this query is showing

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-server-5.6 : Depends: mysql-client-5.6 (>= 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-5.6 (= 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: mysql-common-5.6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I am followoing this [tutorial](http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/05/07/install-mysql-server-5-6-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr/).

How to install this???

Comment: Try this:

`sudo apt-get update` then, `sudo apt-get upgrade` then, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.. finally, try: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: `#sudo apt-get install mysql-server` is showing 
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: did you run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` ?

Answer (score 2):

You must first be sure that your system are updated. To do so, run:

> $ sudo apt-get update
>   $ sudo apt-get upgrade
>   $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

The last command is very important to solve this problem... I had a similar problem and this command was the trick

If no error reported at this stage, run:

> $ sudo apt-get install mysql-server

If the error persists, run:

> $ sudo apt-get -f install mysql-server

Note: Dont Specify the Version

Comment: `# sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:'
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.`

Comment: Then running `#sudo apt-get -f install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Answer (score 1):

You have to install some dependencies, as we can see below :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-server-5.6 : Depends: mysql-client-5.6 (>= 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-5.6 (= 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: mysql-common-5.6 but it is not going to be installed
```

**First** you have to install the dependencies :

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
sudo apt-get install mysql-common-5.6
```

**Finally** you can install the mysql-server :

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

Comment: showing `~# sudo apt get install mysql-server-5.5
E: Invalid operation get
:~# sudo apt get install mysql-server-5.5
E: Invalid operation get
root@ILAND:~# sudo apt get install mysql-common-5.6
E: Invalid operation get
:~# sudo apt get install mysql-server-5.6
E: Invalid operation ge`

Comment: ` #sudo apt-get install mysql-common-5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
`

Comment: Did you enter in the console this line `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5`, before this line `sudo apt-get install mysql-common-5.6` ?

Comment: And when you enter in the console this line `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6`, you still have some errors ?

Comment: This linked helped me solve the same issue although my case was more elaborate http://askubuntu.com/questions/720220/apt-not-installing-most-known-packages